# Calling an async function inside a non-async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I wrote this async function that fetches data from an API.

```
const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}`);
  const json = await response.json();
  return json.results.slice(0,3);
}
```

I expect it to return an array containing 3 objects.

I call the `getData` function in a non-async function

```
function App() {
  const thing = getData().then(data => data);
  console.log("Thing is: " + thing);
}
```

But instead of my array being printed out I'm getting `"Thing is: [object Promise]"` and I don't know why. I've read around and it says that `async` functions will always return a promise, so although my return statement in `getData` defines an array of 3 objects it will ultimately return a promise that is once resolved I can access that array. So I go ahead and then use `.then` when I call the `getData` function, but still I'm getting the promise instead of the data? I think I'm doing something wrong with the arrow function, I don't know if I'm returning the data correctly.

Comment: `getData().then(console.log)`

Comment: @dandavis Yes I noticed that will give me the data but I want to ultimately store the array in a variable. So what would I do instead?

Comment: `var array; function App(){ getData().then(x=>array=x)}` gets it outside the callback. your challenge is then more _when_ to access that var than _where_ to access it.

Comment: @dandavis I did `const thing = getData().then(data => {return data});` and then `console.log(thing)` but the array still doesn't get printed.

Comment: The return value of a `then` function is always a Promise. You can't escape the fact that asynchronous code means that the value won't exist until the future. You have to use a mechanism (like `await` or `then`) to wait until the value is available.